# Angular 7 Why Convert body to JSON string and to Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httpresponse, angular7

Why do I have to convert `event.body` to JSON string and parse back to object?

```
this.excelFileService.upload(this.currentFileUpload).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        let excelFile: ExcelFile = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.body));
        this.excelFiles.push(excelFile);
      }      
    });
```

If I directly pass, `event.body` to `push`, it doesn't compile:

```
ERROR in src/app/excel-file/excel-file.component.ts(54,30): error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExcelFile'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ExcelFile': filename, path, createdAt
```

If I pass `event.body[0]`, it compiles but it is an empty object `{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types are not compatible. Use the following code instead

```js
const excelFile = event.body as ExcelFile;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `JSON.parse` returns `any` as type so no Type error occurs. You need to define the type of `event.body`

```
let excelFile: ExcelFile = event.body as ExcelFile;
```

In that way you are saying to TS compiler "Hey, I know this data has this type"